# How to close a League of Legends account?

Tags: league-of-legends

i created a League of Legends account a long time ago and haven't used it since. Today i got an email about loosing my "Summoner Name". i think i'd prefer just closing (deleting) the account. How do i do that?

Comment: Sorry if this isn't the proper SE site to ask this, i read the on-topic page and went through questions, but still not certain...

Comment: Take a look at [justdelete.me](http://justdelete.me/) in the future. ;)

Comment: @user98085 That site currently says "impossible" for League of Legends (which is incorrect), and the forum page it links to is not valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Contact support about it.](https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202647784-Account-Deletion-FAQ) You can choose to either fully delete or deactivate your account.

> Account deletions will permanently delete all personal information associated with your account. You'll never be able to access the account again, and once it's done, there's no bringing it back.
>
> Account deactivation will restrict access to your account, but all of your account's data will be untouched. No one will be able to log into the account while it is deactivated and your information will remain on our database. This process is reversible at any time upon request. Please note that account deactivation will NOT prevent your ranking from decaying.

For up-to-date instructions on how to do it, you should refer to Riot's support website, linked above for convenience.

Comment: Thank you. So i'll most probably keep getting those emails even if i did that then...

Comment: 404
The page you were looking for doesn't exist

Answer (score 8):

The question and other answer are outdated. **As of now, Novmeber 2016**, you can request to delete your account and **it can be fully deleted within 15 days**:

> Account deletions will permanently delete all the information associated to your account, including username, Summoner name, email address, and purchase history. The account will no longer exist and will never be accessible again. This process is irreversible.

To delete your account, follow the instructions mentioned [in this link](https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202647784-Account-Deletion-FAQ#h2q4). You may also want to read the difference between account deactivation and deletion (both options are available) in the same link.